# How can I use same db session for two procedures in Spring boot

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

I am developing spring boot application with Oracle database and Hikari cp.
In my project I am connecting to db with SimpleJdbcCall.
In database, I have a package and I am calling procedures from Java. Some procedures use global variables from database package.

I set global variables in a procedure. Then I am calling another procedure which is using global variables.

I call first procedure at a filter class and then I call second procedure at service class.

I search at internet and global variables work db session based.

How can I call these two procedures in the same db session?

Comment: Either you have to call both procedures in the same transaction or you have to limit your connection pool with the `max_sessions = 1`

Comment: I want different sessions each request. But in a requst, I want to use same session for multiple db calls. I dont want to limit my connection pool.